# Espacio muy amplio en texto justificado boostrap 4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Estoy intentando justificar y un texto en boostrap 4, pero al usar la clase text-justify el texto se separa demasiado y no luce bien, alguien conoce alguna forma de hacer que no pase esto.
así luce el texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El texto justificado siempre va actuar de esa manera, ten en cuenta que si se ve tan separado es porque tiene que justificarse las 3 palabras con el ancho del párrafo. También aclarar que si la siguiente parabra(Electrónica) pudiera entrar junto con las 3 primeras se vería mucho mejor, pero simplemente "no encaja" esa palabra con ese tamaño de letra en el ancho del contenedor. En fin, es normal que se vea así y tal vez sea solo tu gusto personal, pero si quieres puedes probar con modificar el ancho del contenedor y/o cambiar el tamaño de la letra.